# PIC法の一部　粒子をランダムに設置し内挿・外挿を行う

Tags: python, spyder

粒子の運動から電場などをを計算するPIC（パーティクルインセル）法を用い粒子の計算を行おうと思いますが、粒子をランダムに設置し外挿（メッシュと粒子の位置関係から面積を使って四点に分ける）内挿（外挿の逆）を行う方法が分かりません。初期条件等は適当でわかりやすいもので構いませんのでサンプルコードや参考になりそうな論文ダウンロードなどがありましたら教えていただければ幸いです。ちなみに真ん中に粒子（電荷）があるときの電位計算や電場計算を行うコードは作成することができました。ある領域に粒子を一つランダムに設置するなどでも構いませんので情報をください。
PIC法の計算方法はある程度理解していますので、実際にPythonでコードを書くとどうなるのか知りたいです

Comment: 「計算方法は分かるけど Python のコードが思いつかない」と「そもそも計算方法が分からない」のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 「計算方法はある程度理解していますがPythonでのコードが書けない」です